Get rid of ALL warnings about opening "untrusted" files
Ever since latest Windows 11 Pro update a couple of days ago, I started experiencing (again, after many years of peace) the nasty message asking me, if I am sure that I want to open this or that file:

I used solution provided by one of thousands of blogs about this. And solved this problem by setting custom settings to Internet Zone in Internet Options:

No, the problem is gone, the first warning isn't shown anymore, but instead Windows keeps shooting at me with a warning that I have put my computer into risk:

Is there a way to tell Windows that I know what am I doing, that it doesn't have to try to be smarter than me and to disable all (both) this kind of warnings?
I am on Dell Inc. Latitude 5540 with Windows 11 Pro (10.0.22631 Build 22631), if that matters.

There is no way to disable this particular security feature of Windows. There isn’t one component responsible.  The best you can is unblock those files.

A temporary workaround: use Presentation Mode to suppress all notifications: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/119220-turn-off-presentation-mode-windows.html . That said, it might also suppress some essential notice.

@Ramhound Thank you, but seeing that stupid notification (first screenshot) for nearly each and every JPG photo that I open in IrfanView, only because some dumbass at Microsoft figured out that my own photographs can do a harm to my computer, certainly isn't the best option. This is quite similar to my second question, that you have commented as well -- just a couple a days ago and just before the latest update I wasn't forced to enable this option and I haven't seen any annoying nags when opening every MP3 or JPG downloaded from the Internet.

The biggest stupidity in the whole picture is that since recent update my Windows 11 marks as "downloaded from the Internet" and thus "unsafe" all the my private files that I "download" to my PC from my own OneDrive. I have to confirm "Yes, open" for each and every of my hundreds of thousands photos stored in OneDrive. That's I am asking -- Microsoft has went way wrong with the latest changes / update.

The magic seems to be hidden behind this small three-dot button of the above mentioned notification box:

Clicking first context menu's item seems to be solving the problem.
